# how can I import class of another package into my package

Tags: java, import, nested, package

Write a package called Company. Under this package create one other package called salary.
 This salary package creates two classes "income" and "expenditure". Income class contain Basic, DA and Hra...and "expenditure" contain food, cloth and home exp.

Create a class "Budget" in package company which uses above two classes and calculate savings of family..

My problem is i have used constructor in both the classes "Income" and "Expenditure"..

but there are some problem in Budget class while importing these two classes..

can you explain me how can I write the "Budget" class ???????  Thank you/!!!

Comment: Show us what you tried, and which error(s) you got. And read the lesson about packages in the Java tutorial : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not 100% complete or even a good way to do it, but it might get you to think.

```
package company;

import company.salary.Income;
import company.salary.Expenditure;

public class Budget
{
    private List<Income> credits;
    private List<Expenditure> debits;

    // Other stuff here
    public Money calculateSavings()
    {
        Money savings = new Money();

        for (Income credit : credits)
        {
           savings.add(credit.getValue());
        }
        for (Expenditure debit : debuts)
        {
           savings.sub(debit.getValue());
        }

        return savings;
    }
}


package company.salary;

public class Income
{
    private Money value;

    public Money getValue() { return this.value; }
}

public class Expenditure
{
    private Money value;

    public Money getValue() { return this.value; }
}
```